# Dynamically write to tables in Dataflow

Tags: google-bigquery, apache-beam, dataflow

Working on a pipeline in Dataflow. I need write values to multiple big query table where the desired table names are values in a PCollection.
For example with class `Data` as:

```
 public class Data{
     public List<String> tableName;
     public String id;
     public String value;
}
```

I will have a `PCollection<Data>` and i would like to write row `(id, value)` into all tables in the list `tableNames`.

Is this possible in dataflow? Would i be able to use BigQueryIO.Write?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Dataflow - save the data into multiple BigQuery tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45006923/google-dataflow-save-the-data-into-multiple-bigquery-tables)

Comment: Use `DynamicDestination` or `SerializableFunction` to achieve this. One of our engineers wrote a blog here -> https://shinesolutions.com/2017/12/05/fun-with-serializable-functions-and-dynamic-destinations-in-cloud-dataflow/

Comment: The challenge with this problem is that the list of table names is literally part of the element in the `PCollection`. I don't imagine you'd want to write the list of table names back to BigQuery. Since each element needs to be written to multiple tables, I think the first step to this problem is to create a transform that will fanout a single input element into multiple output elements, with each output element only containing 1 table name. From there, we need to figure out how to exclude the table name from the eventual `TableRow` object that needs to be created.